# How SAML IDP manages username password

Tags: java, single-sign-on, adfs, opensaml, idp

Consider IDP as ADFS, saml is implemented using opensaml. what are the different way in which IDP stores username password so that it will allow user to authenticate without entering username password 2nd time. And how IDP will know user XYZ who loged in previously is trying to login again.

Comment: Any answer would be appreciated